# R: shiny: all components in a panel stretch to 100%

Tags: r, width, shiny

I have a WellPanel which has 2 selectInputs as 2 rows. By default they stretch across the panel. This seems to happen for all panels, for e.g. all components in sidebar panel stretch. Is there a way to set the width to max selection length in options?

Answer (score 0):

```
sidebarPanel(..., width = 4)

sidebarPanel(..., width = "100%")

sidebarPanel(..., width = NULL)
```